# Multiple projects using GitHub pages

Tags: github-pages

I cam across this wonderful developer site https://hihayk.github.io/.

In this site, each link is the OUTPUT of another repository by the developer. For example https://hihayk.github.io/scale/ is the output of https://github.com/hihayk/scale.

Like this several projects are there in this GitHub page.

The code of https://hihayk.github.io/ is just an html & a CSS page !!! https://github.com/hihayk/hihayk.github.io

Can anyone let me know how the contents of each URL (https://hihayk.github.io/scale/ ,https://hihayk.github.io/shaper/ , https://hihayk.github.io/matter/ etc) is being generated?

Any idea as to how this is being done? I know that this is a "conceptual" question than a very specific problem. However, I could not find any resource to understand this hence reach out to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content for https://hihayk.github.io/scale/ is served from the `gh-pages` branch, you can see it here: https://github.com/hihayk/scale/tree/gh-pages

The way the GitHub pages are served can be configured in the Settings: https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#publishing-from-a-branch